# Sort df for highest row value of two columns (of one multicolumn) but keep multicolumn base order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want to sort my df (picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT0TN.png)) maincolumns (every maincolumns consists of 2 subcolumns) by the highest row value of one of this two subcolumns. The row i want to sort it is "Ball Possession". I just know how to sort it for this row but only for the subcolumns directly (picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLTLg.png)). But i want to keep the order of the maincolumns.
picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SebWs.png) shows how the solution ("photoshoped") should look.

```
[The Basis Dataframe i want to sort][1]
[Sort by subcolumns but not maincolumns][2]
[photoshopped solution][3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start off, my `df5` looks like this:

```
>>> df5
           Ball Possession  Result         Team
cat  type
cat0 0                  38       0         PAOK
     2                  62       1      Chelsea
cat1 0                  32       0         PAOK
     2                  68       1      Chelsea
cat2 0                  76       4      Chelsea
     2                  24       1      Cardiff
cat3 0                  78       4      Chelsea
     2                  22       1      Cardiff
cat4 0                  76       2      Chelsea
     2                  24       0  Bournemouth
cat5 0                  70       2      Chelsea
     2                  30       0  Bournemouth
cat6 0                  21       1    Newcastle
     2                  79       2      Chelsea
```

I'm not sure if your dataframe was after `.T` or not. You can switch around if need be. In any case first you need to get the correct ordering of the games by Ball Possession:

```
df6 = df5.reset_index().groupby( 'cat' ).apply( lambda df: df.nlargest( 1, 'Ball Possession' ) )
```

nlargest is picking the greater Ball Possession value per cat0, cat1, cat2.

`df6` looks like:

```
>>> df6
          cat  type  Ball Possession  Result     Team
cat
cat0 1   cat0     2               62       1  Chelsea
cat1 3   cat1     2               68       1  Chelsea
cat2 4   cat2     0               76       4  Chelsea
cat3 6   cat3     0               78       4  Chelsea
cat4 8   cat4     0               76       2  Chelsea
cat5 10  cat5     0               70       2  Chelsea
cat6 13  cat6     2               79       2  Chelsea
```

then finish off

```
order = df6.sort_values( 'Ball Possession', ascending=False )['cat'].values
```

so `order` is just

```
>>> order
array(['cat6', 'cat3', 'cat2', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat1', 'cat0'], dtype=object)
```

and then use that ordering on the original data, sorting on the level:

```
final = df5.reindex( order, level='cat' ).T
```

which gets you

```
cat                   cat6              cat3              cat2              cat4                  cat5               cat1           cat0
type                     0        2        0        2        0        2        0            2        0            2     0        2     0        2
Ball Possession         21       79       78       22       76       24       76           24       70           30    32       68    38       62
Result                   1        2        4        1        4        1        2            0        2            0     0        1     0        1
Team             Newcastle  Chelsea  Chelsea  Cardiff  Chelsea  Cardiff  Chelsea  Bournemouth  Chelsea  Bournemouth  PAOK  Chelsea  PAOK  Chelsea
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Great solution, works perfectly!